# The difference of token in build configuration and in jenkinsfile triggers block

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-pipeline, token

Preconditions: Add a webhook in my repository:

```
http://JenkinsURL:Port/multibranch-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=myToken
```

1. Go to Build Configuration -> Scan Multibranch Pipeline Trigger, Tick "Scan by webhook" and add "myToken" for "Trigger token"
   Push from repository -> build triggered -> work as expected
2. Untick "Scan by webhook" from Build Configuration
   Add a trigger block like below

```
triggers {
    GenericTrigger(
        genericVariables:[
            //some variables
        ],
        token: 'myToken',
        //some configurations
    )
}
stages{
    // ...
}
```

Push from repository -> not build -> not expected behavior, seems `token` not work here

**I wonder** what the difference of these 2 tokens and how I should use *token* in `jenkinsfile`
I get the explations, see my answer below. If any one knows how we can use **Multibranch webhook** in `triggers`

Answer (score 1):

I got the point:
There're 2 webhook plugins:

- **Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin**, receives any HTTP request as `JENKINS_URL/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=GenericToken`. It can be used in *Build Trigger* in *Freestyle project*, *Pipeline* or other project... It also can be added in `triggers` block in *jenkinsfile*.
- **Multibranch Scan Webhook Trigger**, receives any HTTP request as `JENKINS_URL/multibranch-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=MultibranchToken` and can be configured in *Build Configuration* in *Multibranch Pipeline*.
  I don't know if we can use **Multibranch Scan Webhook Trigger** in *jenkinsfile*.

Back to my question, I use **Generic Webhook Trigger** in `triggers` block, but send **Multibranch webhook trigger** from HTTP request. That's why it doesn't work.